# Android- System services not available to Activities before onCreate()

Tags: android, gps

**My problem:**
I'm getting this error System services not available to Activities before onCreate() and i have no idea how to fix it. I've searching and some people talk about the initialization before onCreate() method...
**Waht i want to do?**
It's simple. I'm receiving the heart rate and i put that on a screen "data". When the value of the heart rate it's lower than 40 or bigger than 120 occurs an anomaly and i want get the gps location at the moment (to send to a data base not to put that on the screen) sorry about my english

**Class GPSTracker**

```
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.util.Log;

public class GPSTracker extends Service implements LocationListener {

private final Context mContext;

// flag for GPS status
boolean isGPSEnabled = false;

// flag for network status
boolean isNetworkEnabled = false;

// flag for GPS status
boolean canGetLocation = false;

Location location; // location
double latitude; // latitude
double longitude; // longitude

// The minimum distance to change Updates in meters
private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 10; // 10 meters

// The minimum time between updates in milliseconds
private static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = 1000 * 60 * 1; // 1 minute

// Declaring a Location Manager
protected LocationManager locationManager;

public GPSTracker(Context context) {
    this.mContext = context;
    getLocation();
}

public Location getLocation() {
    try {
        locationManager = (LocationManager) mContext.getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

        // getting GPS status
        isGPSEnabled = locationManager
                .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

        // getting network status
        isNetworkEnabled = locationManager
                .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

        if (!isGPSEnabled && !isNetworkEnabled) {
            // no network provider is enabled
        } else {
            this.canGetLocation = true;
            // First get location from Network Provider
            if (isNetworkEnabled) {
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                        LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                        MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                        MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                Log.d("Network", "Network");
                if (locationManager != null) {
                    location = locationManager
                            .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                    if (location != null) {
                        latitude = location.getLatitude();
                        longitude = location.getLongitude();
                    }
                }
            }
            // if GPS Enabled get lat/long using GPS Services
            if (isGPSEnabled) {
                if (location == null) {
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                            LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                            MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                            MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                    Log.d("GPS Enabled", "GPS Enabled");
                    if (locationManager != null) {
                        location = locationManager
                                .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                        if (location != null) {
                            latitude = location.getLatitude();
                            longitude = location.getLongitude();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return location;
}

/**
 * Stop using GPS listener
 * Calling this function will stop using GPS in your app
 * */
public void stopUsingGPS(){
    if(locationManager != null){
        locationManager.removeUpdates(GPSTracker.this);
    }
}

/**
 * Function to get latitude
 * */
public double getLatitude(){
    if(location != null){
        latitude = location.getLatitude();
    }

    // return latitude
    return latitude;
}

/**
 * Function to get longitude
 * */
public double getLongitude(){
    if(location != null){
        longitude = location.getLongitude();
    }

    // return longitude
    return longitude;
}

/**
 * Function to check GPS/wifi enabled
 * @return boolean
 * */
public boolean canGetLocation() {
    return this.canGetLocation;
}

/**
 * Function to show settings alert dialog
 * On pressing Settings button will lauch Settings Options
 * */
public void showSettingsAlert(){
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);

    // Setting Dialog Title
    alertDialog.setTitle("GPS is settings");

    // Setting Dialog Message
    alertDialog.setMessage("GPS is not enabled. Do you want to go to settings menu?");

    // On pressing Settings button
    alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Settings", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
            mContext.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    // on pressing cancel button
    alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    });

    // Showing Alert Message
    alertDialog.show();
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    return null;
}

}
```

**Class Anomaly**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class Anomaly extends Activity {

GPSTracker gps;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.data);
}

 public void abnormalHRDetected(int heartRateInt) {

    if (heartRateInt < 40 || heartRateInt > 120) {
        //dispara o trigger e escreve na BD o valor
        gps = new GPSTracker(Anomaly.this);

        // check if GPS enabled
        if(gps.canGetLocation()){

            double latitude = gps.getLatitude();
            double longitude = gps.getLongitude();

            // \n is for new line
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your Location is - \nLat: " + latitude + "\nLong: " + longitude, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }else{
            // can't get location
            // GPS or Network is not enabled
            // Ask user to enable GPS/network in settings
            gps.showSettingsAlert();
        }
         //é suposto actualizar a posição e devolver as coordenadas
    }
 }

 private void FallDetected() {
    //dispara o trigger
 }

 private void AbnormalTemperatureDetected(int temperature) {
    //dispara o trigger e escreve na BD o valor
 }

}
```

**logcat**

```
10-19 14:27:06.386 1256-1268/com.example.nunog.myapplication12 D/BluetoothLeService: Received heart rate: 63
    10-19 14:27:06.386 1256-1268/com.example.nunog.myapplication12 D/BleActivityOld: HeartRate: 63
    10-19 14:27:06.386 1256-1268/com.example.nunog.myapplication12 W/System.err: java.lang.IllegalStateException: System services not available to Activities before onCreate()
    10-19 14:27:06.386 1256-1268/com.example.nunog.myapplication12 W/System.err:     at android.app.Activity.getSystemService(Activity.java:4745)
    10-19 14:27:06.386 1256-1268/com.example.nunog.myapplication12 W/System.err:     at com.example.nunog.myapplication12.GPSTracker.getLocation(GPSTracker.java:52)
    10-19 14:27:06.386 1256-1268/com.example.nunog.myapplication12 W/System.err:     at com.example.nunog.myapplication12.GPSTracker.<init>(GPSTracker.java:47)
    10-19 14:27:06.386 1256-1268/com.example.nunog.myapplication12 W/System.err:     at com.example.nunog.myapplication12.Anomaly.abnormalHRDetected(Anomaly.java:24)
    10-19 14:27:06.396 1256-1268/com.example.nunog.myapplication12 W/System.err:     at com.example.nunog.myapplication12.BleActivityOld.getHeartRate(BleActivityOld.java:129)
    10-19 14:27:06.396 1256-1268/com.example.nunog.myapplication12 W/System.err:     at com.example.nunog.myapplication12.BluetoothLeService.getHeartRate(BluetoothLeService.java:136)
    10-19 14:27:06.396 1256-1268/com.example.nunog.myapplication12 W/System.err:     at com.example.nunog.myapplication12.BluetoothLeService.broadcastUpdate(BluetoothLeService.java:155)
    10-19 14:27:06.396 1256-1268/com.example.nunog.myapplication12 W/System.err:     at com.example.nunog.myapplication12.BluetoothLeService.access$500(BluetoothLeService.java:21)
    10-19 14:27:06.396 1256-1268/com.example.nunog.myapplication12 W/System.err:     at com.example.nunog.myapplication12.BluetoothLeService$1.onCharacteristicChanged(BluetoothLeService.java:130)
    10-19 14:27:06.396 1256-1268/com.example.nunog.myapplication12 W/System.err:     at android.bluetooth.BluetoothGatt$1.onNotify(BluetoothGatt.java:423)
    10-19 14:27:06.396 1256-1268/com.example.nunog.myapplication12 W/System.err:     at android.bluetooth.IBluetoothGattCallback$Stub.onTransact(IBluetoothGattCallback.java:403)
    10-19 14:27:06.396 1256-1268/com.example.nunog.myapplication12 W/System.err:     at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:404)
    10-19 14:27:06.396 1256-1268/com.example.nunog.myapplication12 W/System.err:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
```

Comment: `Anomaly` is calling `abnormalHRDetected` before `onCreate`. When are you calling abnormalHRDetected? It looks like from your service, which I can assume is running in the background, potentially after the activity is killed?

Comment: the error you are getting says it clear, just remove your `Service` constructor and move its code to `onCreate` method

Comment: (Slightly off-topic: The `GPSTracker` code is flawed as it requests location updates, but doesn't handle them in `onLocationChanged()`.)

Comment: If the heart rate monitoring code in `BleActivityOld.java` is supposed to display the `Anomaly` activity before it has ever been displayed before, then how about displaying it with an `Intent` with the heart rate in the intent's extra information instead of just calling `abnormalHRDetected()`? The `onCreate()` would be run then. Or if there's nothing to show in the `Activity` then it shouldn't be an `Activity` at all.

Comment: @MarkusKauppinen thank's a lot!!!! That solve my problem!! ufaaaa